# Variable quantifier in perl6

Tags: regex, raku

Suppose i want to match words with at least 4 letters, (and store them in an array), I have written the following regex, which works fine:

```
if ( $text ~~ m:g/(\w ** 4..*)/ )
{
  my @words = $/;
  ... 
}
```

The quantifier being from 4 to unlimited

```
**4..*
```

Now if I try to substitute 4 with a scalar $min_length. Both:

```
if ($text ~~ m:g/(\w ** $::min_length..*)/)
```

and:

```
if ($text ~~ m:g/(\w ** <$::min_length>..*)/)
```

results in an error at compilation:
Quantifier quantifies nothing

Is there a way for having a scalar as a quantifier?

Comment: The error message is terrible. If you like helping devs out a little, please send an email to 'rakudobug@perl.org', with a subject something like '[LTA] "Quantifier quantifies nothing" message for code that actually quantifies something, just with invalid syntax' and a body that includes a minimal version of this problem, the sort of message you'd expect, and the actual error message that Rakudo currently displays. ('LTA', which stands for Less Than Awesome, is a term used in the Perl 6 world for error messages that aren't perfect. This error message is a million miles from perfect!)

Comment: Thanks. I will. The error message is a bit cryptic yes, but at least it pointed to the right place :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the right-hand side of the `**` quantifier is not a number or range literal, but an arbitrary Perl 6 expression, you have to enclose it in braces:

```perl6
my $text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
my $min-length = 4;

my @words = $text.comb(/ \w ** {$min-length .. *} /);

.say for @words;
```

Output:

```
quick
brown
jumps
over
lazy
```

Comment: While struggling to apply this to m//, your solution works well, as well as it saves me for an if-statement and an additional line of assignment. -Thanks

Comment: @Mikkel If you needed that `if` statement, you could also do `if $text.comb(/ …  /) -> @words { … }` or `if $text ~~ m:g/ …  / -> @words { … }`

Answer (score 7):

I think using `.split` is a more natural fit, together with `.grep`:

```
my $text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
my $min-length = 4;
say $text.split(/\W+/).grep(*.chars >= $min-length);
===============
(quick brown jumps over lazy)
```

If you define words as the characters between whitespace, you can even use the `.words` method:

```
say $text.words.grep(*.chars >= $min-length);
===============
(quick brown jumps over lazy dog.)
```

Comment: `$text.comb(/ \w+ /).grep(*.chars >= $min-length);` also works. To me, `split` only feels more natural than `comb` in case of static delimiters, otherwise it's a bit of a double-negation - "gimme all words" is easier to reason about than "gimme all fields that are not part of not-words".